# Terminal cannot find commands, and downloads (wget) not working

Tags: apt, bash, package-management, dpkg, wget

I think I've damaged my Ubuntu installation, as now it is not recognising some terminal commands such as ufw/glances (which are already installed). The result is as follows.

```
-bash: ufw: command not found
```

Also `sudo apt update --fix-missing` is not not working, as it gives the following results.

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                       
  Temporary failure resolving 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                      
  Temporary failure resolving 'gb.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease      
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:5 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gluster/glusterfs-3.12/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:7 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gluster/glusterfs-6/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Reading package lists... Done       
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'gb.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gluster/glusterfs-3.12/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gluster/glusterfs-6/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This happened when I tried to downgrade the python version from 3.8 to 3.5 to run a specific programme, in ubuntu 20.2. I only saw the comments not recommending the procedures a little late, which was too late at the moment.

Couple of notes: my path is as follows `(and it contains bin, /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin)`

```
/home/chameera/.local/bin:/opt/lib/mpich/bin:/opt/lib/netcdf/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

- using wget, cannot download any file, but can ssh into and out of the machine, as well as transfer files
- ping to 8.8.8.8 responds, but doesn't respond to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
- `sudo dpkg --configure -a` does not generate any output after clearing the lock files in `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`, `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`, `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend`, `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`

I have not yet rebooted the machine as it is a remote machine and a little bit worried to do so, fearing that I may loose access to it again until I physically recover the machine. I would be so grateful if any of you can help me out in this regard.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20.02 release (ie. no release in 2020-February), so I'd check your details.  I'd suggest reversing your changes; as many tools in Ubuntu require python3 to be the default version it comes with; otherwise you're limited to base tools only (ie. no higher level tools like `apt`  or `apt-get`...)  FYI:  `wget` should still work, as should `dpkg` - however many user-level tools you normally use to correct networking issues may not work until you correct the python3 issue.  You `ping` issue highlights DNS issues; correct manually if needs be.  You should not *clean* lock files!

Answer (score 1):

You need to undo your downgrade of python, I'm not sure how you did it.

After that is fixed, I would recommend either using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) to manage other python versions (never touch system python!) or installing CPython separately in another directory tree, such as `/opt/python/<version>`.  With the latter option, you can use [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) or [Lmod](https://lmod.readthedocs.io) to swap software versions in and out easily, similarly to python virtual environments or conda environments.